# How to publish dem(.tif) data with geoserver

Tags: tiff, geoserver

I am new to the geoserver, now i want to publish the dem data that is type of tif so that I can get it from WebWorldWind with WMS and the dem data should be with format of application/bil16. Anybody can tell me how can i do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) manual has a section on how to [add a GeoTiff coverage](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/geotiff.html).

However `application/bil16` is not a supported output type by default, so you will need to follow [these instructions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/dds/index.html) on how to add the DDS/Bil extension.

Comment: thanks iant, i have changed the source code of DDS/Bil to return the application/bil16.

Comment: Can you submit a pull request for that please

Comment: sure, where is the address?

Comment: Github.com/geoserver